# How to adjust volume during movie playback on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, control-center

A recent update to iOS 11 eliminated the volume control, which used to be in the corner of the screen when you tapped a movie as it was playing.   My iPad is on a stand and the physical volume controls are not as easily accessed.  I found that I can do a cumbersome double-swipe up from the bottom of the screen, and sometimes get to the control center.  Sometimes I just get the home bar and have to try a third or fourth swipe.  Once I get the control center, the movie shrinks (while still playing) into a tiny window near other apps that are running.  Then, I can tap on the volume control, which looks a bit like a white and black thermometer now, and hold my finger for a while.  It will enlarge and the everything including the movie will blur.  Once it is enlarged, IF I keep my finger on it, I can slide the volume up and down, but if I accidentally remove my finger the control is unresponsive, and I need to collapse it again and press and hold a while more to start over.  Finally, I get to adjust the volume.   Once set, I can tap anywhere in the blurred screen to return to the tiny windows and then select the one containing my movie which has been playing.  It will enlarge again and I will then slide the movie playback controls to find where I was in the movie before I started this complex adventure in volume control.

If you're like me, you may find yourself wanting to quickly adjust the volume up and down during a movie.  If your device is on a stand, how do you do it?  Is there another volume control or way to open an easier to use interface for quickly adjusting volume as you watch a movie?

Comment: In safari, I still have volume controls for a full screen video. What app?

Comment: In every app I've used which uses the iOS video player, the volume is in the top right corner. When you do use the hardware buttons, where does the volume change alert appear?

Answer (score 1):

I allowed an update to iOS again last night to **v11.0.2** and Apple has fixed the problem.   They added the volume control back, and it is in the bottom left corner.  To access it, simply tap anywhere while a movie is playing.